# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,384) (96,) (11,384)

Tags: python, numpy, spacy

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

vecs1 = [] <br>
for qu1 in tqdm(list(train_df['question1'])):<br>
    doc1 = nlp(qu1) <br>
    mean_vec1 = np.zeros([len(doc1), 384])<br>
    for word1 in doc1:<br>
        vec1 = word1.vector<br>
        try: <br>
            idf = word2tfidf[str(word1)]<br>
        except:<br>
            idf = 0<br>
        # compute final vec<br>
        mean_vec1 += (vec1 * idf)<br>
    mean_vec1 = mean_vec1.mean(axis=0)<br>
    vecs1.append(mean_vec1)<br>
train_df['q1_feats_m'] = list(vecs1)
```

i got this error for above code

---

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        18             idf = 0
>        19         # compute final vec
>   ---> 20         mean_vec1 += (vec1 * idf)
>        21     mean_vec1 = mean_vec1.mean(axis=0)
>        22     vecs1.append(mean_vec1)
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,384) (96,) (11,384)

Comment: some context on what you're trying to achieve would be helpful!

Comment: i'm trying to get tfidfw2v using glove

Comment: I am also running in same problem. Let me know if you solve it.

Comment: yeah i got this solution for this in above error we got broadcasting (11,384) (96,)(11,384), here 96 is the dimensions what we have in our data what what we initialized is 384(see above code)  its miss matching so change value to 384 to 96 it will run smoothly i.e...,(11,96) (96,) (11,96)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this here to allow for entire code to be pasted.

Without knowing your data it's hard to say. Add the following print command lines to verify the shape of your arrays. From the error it seems your vec1 (96,) and idf (11,384) which cannot be multiplied!

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

vecs1 = []
for qu1 in tqdm(list(train_df['question1'])):
    doc1 = nlp(qu1)
    mean_vec1 = np.zeros([len(doc1), 384])
    for word1 in doc1:
        vec1 = word1.vector
        try: 
            idf = word2tfidf[str(word1)]
        except:
            idf = 0

        # Debug Prints
        print("idf Shape: %s" %idf.shape)
        print("vec1 Shape: %s" %vec1.shape)
        print("mean_vec1 Shape: %s" %mean_vec1.shape)


        # compute final vec
        mean_vec1 += (vec1 * idf)
    mean_vec1 = mean_vec1.mean(axis=0)
    vecs1.append(mean_vec1)
train_df['q1_feats_m'] = list(vecs1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this i got it